Estimate confidence interval of a cubic B-spline fit
I have a non-linear system. I apply multiple inputs x(t) (t=time) and measure each response y(t).
In other words, I have inputs x1(t), x2(t), x3(t), xn(t) and I measure y1(t), y2(t), y3(t), yn(t) for the given non-linear system.
I fit a cubic B-spline (using scipy splrep and knots) through the points y1(t), y2(t), y3(t), yn(t), so I get a y(t) which is my cubic B-spline fit.
I like to estimate the confidence interval of the cubic B-spline fit.
My questions

is bootstrapping the way to go?
are there other methods?


this post might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852505/how-to-get-confidence-interval-for-smooth-spline
